# Margins in Visual Basic Editor Excel 2016

Tags: macos, visual-studio, excel, vba

My visual basic editor only allows me to type in one column. In other words, only one letter per line. Please see the image below. How do I fix this? (visual basic for mac)

[image: one column visual basic editor]

Answer (score 4):

This is a bug in Excel.  To fix this, you simply need to update Excel.  Click "Help" > "Check for Updates", then close Excel. Next, click the "Check for Updates" button in the Microsoft AutoUpdate window, and select for Excel to update.  After updating, when you reopen Excel the problem will be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, found the answer here : 
http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/mac/forum/macoffice2016-macexcel/visual-basic-support-in-mac-2016/4afbba04-4435-4970-8b02-40da006a590e?auth=1

MS has no plans to push the VB editor forward on the Mac...Wonder if they put that on the glossy brochure for office 2016?

Comment: Link-only answers are not helpful. Include the relevant information in your answer.

Comment: @miken32, In my defense, when I answered this question I didn't have enough rep to comment.